# Login web application with local user

Tags: java, windows

To using a computer I need inform a network user to connect. So, I wanna know if it is possible to connect to a web application using 
the local user without putting again the user and password. In other words, I need to recognize the local user to auto authentication when entering the web application.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is this userbase accessibele with ldap? If so maybe use ldap to authenticate against.

Comment: Yes it is. Now what is your context? What technologies are you working with?

Comment: I try to always use services with lldap built in if not I just found adldap. adLDAP is a PHP class that provides LDAP authentication and integration with Active Directory.

Comment: @SteinvanBroekhoven So, using the ldap authentication I can log in a web application using a local user?

Comment: @kolossus I only have an intranet developed by java and zk framework. And there a web application that I want to use the local user. And as said have a ldap server for authentication. My initial interest is to find a method in which it is possible to study for then I can make it.

Comment: Is this a "local domain user", local Linux user ?

Comment: @SteinvanBroekhoven Is a "local domain user"

Comment: I think this is a good starting point: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php#99347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand the question correctly but, wouldn't a

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```

get you the username? As for pulling the users password I doubt that would be easy, but I don't think a user would mind too much putting in the password again if their username autopopulated.

Comment: Using System.getProperty it's impossible to get a password, it will just return a user name. I wanna a automatic login using the local user. I don't know if it is possible but for example a server ldap when I log on my computer, it return a variable and when i will log in a web application, I will set this variable and the class will recognize and log the user. Of course it is not that simple and the way I described is wrong but it's only to demonstrate what I want. But thanks =]

Comment: No problem. But you should really just prompt the user for their password again. It's a hit you might have to take if you can't find another way to design it.